# Return two dimension array from function in C

Tags: c, pointers, types, matrix-multiplication

I input a matrix into a function and I want to output the multiplication of it by itself. I can't manage to return the result in the correct format.

```
int **multiplyMatrix(int matrixA[10][10], int matrixB[10][10], int n)
{
    int matrixC[10][10] = { 0 };
    int rowC, columnC = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int* ptr = matrixC;
    for (rowC = 0; rowC < n; rowC++)
    {
        for (columnC = 0; columnC < n; columnC++)
        {
            i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                matrixC[rowC][columnC] += matrixA[rowC][i] * matrixB[i][columnC];
            }
        }
    }
    return *ptr;
}
```

the multiplication works fine, if I print the matrix in the function I get the correct result but I can't menage to get the values back to main()

```
void main()
{
    int n=2;
    int matrixA[10][10] = { 0 };
    int result[10][10] = { 0 };
    
    setMatrix(matrixA, n); // set values from user to the matrix
    printMatrix(matrixA, n); // print matrix in format

    **result = multiplyMatrix(matrixA, matrixA, n);
    printMatrix(result, n);
}
```

in result is only the correct value of result[0][0], all other values are still 0.

for example, matrix A has the values of {1,2,3,4} and after multiplication its {7,10,15,22} but in main() result values are {7,0,0,0}. how do I set the other values from the matrix in multiplyMatrix() to result I main?

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers.  Arrays of `int` decay to pointers to `int`.  Arrays of `double` decay to pointers to `double`.  Arrays of arrays decay to pointers to arrays -- *not* pointers to pointers.

Answer (score 5):

You have two problems here.

First, the return type of the function doesn't match what you're returning.  The expression `*ptr` has type `int[10]` which decays to `int *`, and the function returns `int **`.  You presumably want to return the whole 2D array, not just one row of it, so the function would have to return a `int (*)[10]` i.e. a pointer to an array of size 10.

This then leads to the second problem.  Even if you returned the correct type, you're returning a pointer to a local variable.  That variable's lifetime ends when the function returns, and dereferencing a pointer to a variable that no longer exists triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The simplest solution here is to simply pass the result array to the function and populate that instead of a local.

```
void multiplyMatrix(int matrixA[10][10], int matrixB[10][10], 
                    int matrixC[10][10], int n)
{
    int rowC, columnC = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (rowC = 0; rowC < n; rowC++)
    {
        for (columnC = 0; columnC < n; columnC++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                matrixC[rowC][columnC] += matrixA[rowC][i] * matrixB[i][columnC];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n=2;
    int matrixA[10][10] = { 0 };
    int result[10][10] = { 0 };
    
    setMatrix(matrixA, n); // set values from user to the matrix
    printMatrix(matrixA, n); // print matrix in format

    multiplyMatrix(matrixA, matrixA, result, n);
    printMatrix(result, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using built-in multidimensional arrays in C is usually not practical. Often it's better to use structures, accompanied with functions that take them as parameters. These structures can hold all metadata you need (array dimensions etc).

In the following example, you can see how to easily create and use 2D matrices in C. They work with data managed externally. Here, stack allocated data is used (adata, bdata, cdata), but there's no problem to use dynamically allocated data.

The last matrix, called cutout, is a sub-matrix of the matrix c.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct matrix {
    int* data;
    int width;
    int height;
    int stride;
} matrix;

matrix* matrixInitWithStride(matrix* m, int* data, int width, int height, int stride) {
    m->data = data;
    m->width = width;
    m->height = height;
    m->stride = stride;
    return m;
}

matrix* matrixInit(matrix* m, int* data, int width, int height) {
    return matrixInitWithStride(m, data, width, height, width);
}

matrix matrixNew(int* data, int width, int height) {
    matrix m;
    return *matrixInit(&m, data, width, height);
}

matrix matrixNewSubmatrix(matrix* m, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    matrix n;
    return *matrixInitWithStride(&n, m->data + y * m->stride + x, width, height, m->stride);
}

int matrixValue(matrix* m, int x, int y) {
    return m->data[y * m->stride + x];
}

void matrixSetValue(matrix* m, int x, int y, int value) {
    m->data[y * m->stride + x] = value;
}

matrix* matrixFill(matrix* m, int value)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < m->height; ++y)
        for (int x = 0; x < m->width; ++x)
            matrixSetValue(m, x, y, value);
    return m;
}

matrix* matrixAdd(matrix* a, matrix* b, matrix* c) {
    for (int y = 0; y < a->height; ++y)
        for (int x = 0; x < a->width; ++x)
            matrixSetValue(c, x, y, matrixValue(a, x, y) + matrixValue(b, x, y));
    return c;
}

void matrixPrint(matrix* m) {
    for (int y = 0; y < m->height; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < m->width; ++x) {
            printf("%5d", matrixValue(m, x, y));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int adata[5 * 5];
    matrix a = matrixNew(adata, 5, 5);
    matrixFill(&a, 1);

    int bdata[a.width * a.height];
    matrix b = matrixNew(bdata, a.width, a.height);
    matrixFill(&b, 2);

    int cdata[a.width * a.height];
    matrix c = matrixNew(cdata, a.width, a.height);
    matrixAdd(&a, &b, &c);
    
    matrix cutout = matrixNewSubmatrix(&c, 1, 1, 3, 3);
    matrixFill(&cutout, 0);
    
    matrixPrint(&c);
    
    return 0;
}
```